# JEditorPane, httpClient and child images

Tags: java, swing, apache-httpclient-4.x, jeditorpane

Currently I use `JEditorPane` to display a simple HTML page with images and a link.

Now I would like to use httpClient 4.x from Apache to get HTML page instead of sun `UrlConnection`

Is it possible with `JEditorPane`?

Is there another swing component able to display simple HTML and in which we can plug httpClient?

I've just try override the `getSream` method of `JEditorPane` (like that : [HttpClient - Cookies - and JEditorPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792855/httpclient-cookies-and-jeditorpane) )

It work fine for the HTML document but httpclient is not used to download child images.

Comment: *"Thanks

Fred."*  That's 4 lines of noise.  Please leave noise out of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load images and place them in the local cache.

http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html

Not sure it helps

Comment: Thanks, it is a idea... but if have to know which image to download, and therefore, I have to parse the html document and doing a job already done in JEditorPane...

Comment: You can implement your own imageCache e.g. by overriding get() method of the Hashtable used in example. Just call super if null is returned load the requested image and store in the cache.