# JEditorPane does not set any HTML

Tags: java, html, image, swing, jeditorpane

I have searched and haven't seen anyone experiencing what I am.. yet, but this is the issue I am having:

I am trying to set a small bit of HTML as the text of my JEditorPane. 
Here is the code:

```
JEditorPane htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
String imageString = "<img   src=\"http://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/thumb/3/37/Optimusg1.jpg/350px-Optimusg1.jpg\"/>";
String description = "<table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0></table>" + imageString + "</table>";
htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
htmlPane.setText(description);
```

but after I call setText, my editor pane contents are:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried variations of adding `<html>` and `</html>` to the beginning and end of my string, but no luck. Anyone know what I am missing or doing wrong?

I am using Java 1.7.0_55 32-bit.

Comment: Beware of two things, first, you example won't compile, second, you HTML is malformed, it should be prefixed with `<html><body>` and suffixed with `</body></html>`

Comment: Not to mention that you HTML `table` has no rows or cells...

Comment: @MadProgrammer It does compile because I have ran it. Even if I remove the table and just have the image, the HTML still does not get set. I also mentioned in the original post that I have tried adding <html> and </html> to the beginning and end of my string, this should imply I have tried <body></body>, etc. (fixed my original post, I didn't wrap "<html>" in code which is why it didn't show in the last paragraph.

Comment: `"<table width=300 border=0 cellspacing=0><img   src="http` won't compile, because you've closed the `String` quotation at the end of `src="`...In my testing, `<html><body><table><tr><td>...</td></tr></body></html>` works...to a point...

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I simplified it for this post. The actual code is a concatenation of strings.

Comment: These things happen, you just need to beware as it can send people of on the wrong tangent ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little testing I found that...

- The HTML has to be well formed before the `JEditorPane` will accept it, and in fact, it seems to do some of it's own validation, removing invalid tags...fun stuff
- I had to include the table row and cell `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` into the table
- Some sites may actively block the downloading of images if the HTTP headers do not have the appropriate headers, this meant that the image you had in your example repeatedly failed to download in the `JEditorPane`, even though the same HTML would load the image in a browser (like Chrome)
- It's sometimes helpful to add additional content into the HTML to make sure it's rendering what you think, for example, I simply added some text, set the table border to `1` and add an `alt` tag to the image, which helped verify certain elements where actually been rendered...

[image: Editor]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestEditorPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestEditorPane();
    }

    public TestEditorPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JEditorPane htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
                String description = "<html><body>Hello<table border=1><tr><td><img alt='Bad' src='http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/084/c/0/angry_wet_ponies_are_angry____by_tabby444-d4tyfsc.png'/></tr></td></table></body></html>";
                htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
                htmlPane.setText(description);
                System.out.println(htmlPane.getText());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(htmlPane));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. having all the table row tags in place set the html right, but the image won't download. You mentioned "Some sites may actively block the downloading of images if the HTTP headers to have appropriate headers", can you explain this?

Comment: A HTTP request can also carry the `user-agent` header as part of the requests.  Some sites actively block request that don't carry an appropriate `user-agent` value

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792855/httpclient-cookies-and-jeditorpane) for taking control of the page request for a `JEditorPane`