# Enable cookies in a Java browser?

Tags: java

I have a browser written in Java, this is third party code, I'm using it for learning purposes.

Is there a way that I could enable cookies in this browser?

Browser code: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-simple-browser-in-swing-18.html

Comment: Answer is "yes, there is", but the rest is pretty broad, so how about asking a bit narrowed down question? Any specific problems with the implementation, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpClient - Cookies - and JEditorPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792855/httpclient-cookies-and-jeditorpane)

Comment: Could you enable it? Sure! You enable it the same way you enabled a browser in Java: you build it.